# DrRacket BNF grammar

Tags: numbers, racket, bnf

I write a BNF grammar like this:

```
#lang pl

#| BNF for the LE language:
   <LE> ::= <num>
          | <null>
|#

(define-type LE
  [Num Number]
)
```

but I am not sure how to check if this code are good...
how to check in racket the the only thing that we can use its null and numbers?

I think something like that:

```
(test 5)
```

but

```
(test '())
```

working too, and I am not setting List in my BNF

(if this code are not good - I will be happy for some BNF example and checking...)

Comment: Since the language `pl` is not part of the main distribution, you will need to give some more information. Is the `pl` language from Bremner's course? (http://www.cs.unb.ca/~bremner/teaching/cs3613/racket-setup/ ). If so which version of Racket is it for?

Answer (score 1):

Without testing I suggest trying the following program:

```
#lang pl

#| BNF for the LE language:
   <LE> ::= <num>
          | <null>
|#

(define-type LE
  [Num Number]
  [Nul Null]
  [Kons LE LE])

(: test : LE -> LE)
(define (test x)
   x)

(test (Num 5))        ; this is accepted since 5 is a Number
(test (Nul '())
(test (Kons (Num 1) (Num 2)))
; (test (Num "foo"))  ; this provokes an error (as it should)
```

Note that `(: test : LE -> LE)` declares the types of the `test` function. Since in `(test '())` the empty list does not match the `LE` type, you ought to get an error.

EDIT: The examples has been update to use `(Num 5)` and not just `5`.

EDIT 2: Added Kons

Comment: the first test give me error:
Type Checker: type mismatch
  expected: Num
  given: Positive-Byte in: 5

Comment: I have update the code. PS: The pl language is available from pl.barzilay.org

Comment: tnx a lot, and the last one. how to check the "null" in the test?

Comment: sorry for a lot of questions but i promise the last one.
how to setting the function "cons" (lists union) into my BNF ?

Comment: Added Kons. See above.

Comment: and how to setting it in the BNF comment?

Comment: The BNF is the comment above the code <LE> ::= ,,,
i need to setting the cons there

Comment: Consult your text and see how they do.